# When I add a new item to a List<List<string>> each item of the parent list get the same values

Tags: c#, generic-list

Apologies if the answer to this is obvious, I'm fairly new to C# and OOP. I've stepped though my code and spent quite some time on Google but I can't find the answer to my question (quite possibly because I am using the wrong search terms!).

I have the following class that creates a static `List<List<string>>` and has a method to add items to that list:

```
public static class WordList
    {
    static List<List<string>> _WordList; // Static List instance

    static WordList()
    {
        //
        // Allocate the list.
        //
        _WordList = new List<List<string>>();
    }

    public static void Record(List<string> Words)
    {
        //
        // Record this value in the list.
        //
        _WordList.Add(Words);
    }
}
```

Else where I create a `List<string>` which I pass into the `Record()` method to be added to `_WordList`. The problem is when I add items to WordList it gives every item in that list the same value. e.g.:

1st item added contains "Foo" and "bar"

2nd item added contains "Not","Foo" and "bar"

So instead of a list that looks like:

```
1: "Foo","bar"
2: "Not","Foo","bar"
```

I end up with:

```
1: "Not","Foo","bar"
2: "Not","Foo","bar"
```

I haven't used a `List<string[]>` instead of a `List<List<string>>` because the way I am getting the `List<string>` to add is by reading a text file line by line with a delimiter saying when I should add the `List<string>` and clear it so I can start again. Therefore I don't know how long an array I need to declare.

Hope this makes some kind of sense! If you need anymore of the code posting to help let me know.

Thanks, in advance.

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the creation of the `List<string>` that is passed to the `Record()` method. I think I see what people are saying about not creating a new instance of the `List<string>` but I'm not sure how to remedy this in regards to my code. I will have a think about it and post an answer if I come up with one!

```
public static void LoadWordList(string path)
    {
        string line;
        List<string> WordsToAdd = new List<string>();

        StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Substring(0, 1) == "$")
            {
                    WordList.Record(WordsToAdd);
                    WordsToAdd.Clear();
                    WordsToAdd.Add(line.Replace("$", ""));
            }
            else
            {
                WordsToAdd.Add(line.Replace("_"," "));
            }
        }
        file.Close();
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're reusing the same `List` instance in your inner loop, maybe clearing it once in a while. Since `List` is a reference type, you need to create a unique instance for each item in your array, or all the items will end up referring to the same list.

Comment: Backticks (`) are your friend for putting code inline in your question, and avoids having to use &lt;, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that your `Record` method is doing is adding a reference to the `List<string>` you've passed to it. You then clear that same list, and start adding different strings to it.

Maybe something like:

```
public static void Record(IEnumerable<string> Words)
{
    _WordList.Add(Words.ToList());
}
```

Which will force a copy to occur; also, by accepting `IEnumerable<string>`, it puts less restrictions on the code that calls it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Thank you to everyone else who left an answer or comment as well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
WordList.Record(WordsToAdd);
WordsToAdd.Clear();
WordsToAdd.Add(line.Replace("$", ""));
```

do

```
WordList.Record(WordsToAdd);
WordsToAdd = new List<string>();
WordsToAdd.Add(line.Replace("$", ""));
```

Answer (score 3):

Can you post the code that adds the list - I bet you are doing something like

1. create a list l
2. add it
3. modify l
4. add it

This result in a single object (because you created it only once) with multiple references to it, namely from the first value in _WordList, from the second value in _WordList, from l.

So the right way to do it is:

1. create list l
2. add it
3. create NEW list l
4. add it

Or in code:

```
List<string> l = new string[] { "Foo", "bar" }.ToList();
WordList.Record(l);
l = new string[] { "Not", "Foo", "bar" }.ToList();
WordList.Record(l);
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I've edited my post with the code used to create the List<string> to pass and as you can see I do use the same List<string> each time. I guess I need to figure out how to create a new list each time.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown how you are adding items to the list. Here's an example which works as expected:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class WordList
{
    static List<List<string>> _WordList; // Static List instance

    static WordList()
    {
        _WordList = new List<List<string>>();
    }

    public static void Record(List<string> Words)
    {
        _WordList.Add(Words);
    }

    public static void Print()
    {
        foreach (var item in _WordList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-----");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item.ToArray()));
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WordList.Record(new[] { "Foo", "bar" }.ToList());
        WordList.Record(new[] { "Not", "Foo", "bar" }.ToList());

        WordList.Print();
    }
}
```